# VS2008 Resize text editor macro

Tags: visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I split my text editor into two vertical text editors. I thought it would be useful to have a macro that re-size the active text editor to take up most of the screen but I haven't gotten very far. I get an error whenever I try to change the width oh a text editor.

```
DTE.ActiveWindow.Width = 800
```

And I'm not sure how to identify weather the active window is a text editor or not.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.window.kind.aspx) property. Should be `"Document"` for text editors, I suppose:

```
If DTE.ActiveWindow.Kind = "Document" Then
    ' ActiveWindow is a text editor '
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyone know why setting the width is causing an error?